# How to return error message objects to the client in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, server

I have this block of code:

```
router.post('/users/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    const user = await User.findByCredentials(email, password)
    console.log(user) //false
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error('Login failed! Check authentication credentials')
    }
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
    res.status(200).json({ user, token })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err) //Error: Login failed! Check authentication credentials at C:\Users...
    res.status(400).json(err)
  }
})
```

It works all fine until there is no Error. When error occur (`user` is `false`) in Postman I have only empty object returned `{}`. Also with `res.status(400).json({error: err})` it gives me `{ "err": {} }`.

I want to receive object like this `{ "error": "Login failed! Check authentication credentials" }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` [can't capture non-enumerable object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15733938/6243352) as jfriend00 mentions but there are some pretty direct solutions that seem worth mentioning.

One way is to create the correct object yourself using the `err.message` property, which contains the string provided to the `Error` constructor:

```
app.get("/foo", (req, res) => {
  try {
    throw Error("hello world");
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({error: err.message});
  }
});
```

Another approach if you really can't touch your `res.json` call is to `throw` an object set up how you like it. I don't like this because you lose stack trace information (see: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501348/6243352), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46295341/6243352), [3](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2009/03/10/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors-part-2/)), but it exists:

```
app.get("/foo", (req, res) => {
  try {
    throw {error: "hello world"};
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }
});
```

In both cases, the client sees

```
{
    error: "hello world"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Error objects don't serialize well in JSON because some of their properties are non-enumerable and thus `JSON.stringify()` does not include them when `res.json(err)` uses it.
That's why `res.json(err)` doesn't show what you want.

Possible reasons why non-enumerable properties are not included is that they may contain stack traces and other information that is not meant to be sent back to the client.    That's just a by-product of how the Error object works and how `JSON.stringify()` is implemented and `res.json()` just inherits those issues and the interaction between the two.  I've never understood why the main `.message` property is non-enumerable as that has never made sense to me, but it is.

There are a number of possible work-arounds:

1. You could add your own `.json2()` method that includes all properties of an Error object (even non-enumerable ones).
2. You could use the [Express error handling scheme](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) where you call `next(err)` and you supply a centralized error handler that gets called and you can do your own serialization of the error response there.
3. You could make a subclass of Error that populates enumerable properties that will show up in JSON and use that.

Option #3 could look like this:

```
class RouteError extends Error {
    constructor(msg, statusCode = 500) {
        super(msg);
        // define my own enumerable properties so they
        // will show up in JSON automatically
        this.error = msg;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
}

router.post('/users/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    const user = await User.findByCredentials(email, password)
    console.log(user) //false
    if (!user) {
      throw new RouteError('Login failed! Check authentication credentials', 401)
    }
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
    res.status(200).json({ user, token })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err) //Error: Login failed! Check authentication credentials at C:\Users...
    res.status(err.statusCode).json(err);
  }
});
```

This example would generate this response:

```
{"error":"Login failed! Check authentication credentials","statusCode":401}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer it is really helpful, `res.status(400).json({ error: err.message })` also works as i wanted.

Comment: @kapsztat12 - Yep, your suggestion is nice and simple.  I still have no idea why the `.message` property is set to non-enumerable.  I get why the `.stack` is.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an error in case the user is null or empty. Another thread answers a similar question.

[Node.js with Express - throw Error vs next(error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794750/node-js-with-express-throw-error-vs-nexterror)

Comment: They already are throwing an error.  That's what isn't working the way they want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the message property of the Error class for making it enumerable. You don't need to use other property for error message like the below answer using error propery.

I searched for implementation of Error class in 'core-js'

[image]

[https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/internals/wrap-error-constructor-with-cause.js#:~:text=if%20(message%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%20createNonEnumerableProperty(result%2C%20%27message%27%2C%20message)%3B](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/internals/wrap-error-constructor-with-cause.js#:%7E:text=if%20(message%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%20createNonEnumerableProperty(result%2C%20%27message%27%2C%20message)%3B)

So, if you want message should be displayed in console or delivered by JSON you should use the following code

```js
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor (message) {
    // super(message)
    super() // avoid message's non-enumerable property

    this.name = this.constructor.name
    this.message = message;

    // needed for CustomError instanceof Error => true
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);

    // Maintains proper stack trace for where our error was thrown (only available on V8)
    if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you can send with this code

```
const err = new CustomError('Custom Error...');

...

res.send(err);
```